# Как отследить загрузку процессора?

Tags: c#, производительность

Требуется создать аналог диспетчера задач. Использование цп процессами отслеживаю с помощью PerformanceCounter. Нашел на сайте microsoft [пример](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15f62541-22a6-413f-9f46-9a14c9d8c94f/cpu-usage-of-process?forum=csharplanguage) и попытался адаптировать со своим классом для инкапсуляции свойств процесса и данных о CPU в одном объекте.

```
class MyProcess : IDisposable
{
    private Process process { get; set; }
    private PerformanceCounter performance;
    ...
    public float CPUusage { get { return performance.NextValue(); } }

    public MyProcess(Process process)
    {
        this.process = process;
        performance = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", process.ProcessName, true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        performance.Dispose();
    }
}
```

При отображении заметил что сумарно используется больше 100%. Также при закрытии одного из процессов мое свойство(CPUusage ) выкидывает исключение которое я не могу отловить в коде. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Листинг кода отображения перегружен ради табличного стиля, он по сути он неотличим от того что в примере.

Помогите понять как получить нагрузку на процессор конкретным процессом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.к. счетчик `\Process(…)\% Processor Time` показывает N*100 нагрузки, где N - кол-во ядер процессора, то чтобы использовать усредненную загрузку по всем ядрам нужно использовать счетчик `\Processor(…)\% Processor Time`:

Подробнее [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnetinterop/2007/02/02/system-diagnostics-performancecounter-and-processor-time-on-multi-core-or-multi-cpu/).